# how to Start the job right now with node-cron

Tags: node.js, cron

I was using node-cron to do something.I write the code like the [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) demo below :

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var myJob = new cronJob('0 */10 * * * *', function(){
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
},function(){

},true);
console.log('now is ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
myJob.start();
```

Iwant to start the job right now when i start, so the third args i make it true.But it dosen't work.What should i do to start the job right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Iwant to start the job right now when i start, so the third args i make it true.

Fourth argument, not third*

```
myJob.start();
```

This line is unnecessary, and might cause some side effects. As you already started your job in constructor by setting 4th argument to `true`.

But the code you shown looks valid. What makes you think it does not work? You have set it to run each 10 minutes, have you waited for clock to be XX:X0:00 to see if the code?

For sake of testing, you could change `'0 */10 * * * *'` to `'* * * * * *'` to see if the code works without waiting.

Comment: thank you first of all,i have doen some test like you said.my code :

    var CronJob  = require('cron').CronJob;
    var myJob = new CronJob('*/10 * * * * *', function(){
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
    },function(){
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString() + ' task stop!');
    }, function(){},true);
    console.log('now is ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
    setTimeout(function(){
        myJob.stop();
    },20000);

Comment: the console :

    now is Wed Jun 11 2014 11:10:47 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
    Wed Jun 11 2014 11:10:50 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
    Wed Jun 11 2014 11:11:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
    Wed Jun 11 2014 11:11:07 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间) task stop!
    
as you see,the job started dely 3 seconds.

Comment: Are you saying that the job was 3 seconds later than you expected it? The output of the program looks correct to me. It printed twice on :50 and :00, in cron you specify '*/10', thus on 00, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50..  Clarifying few facts: starting the job right now, means it is ON and will execute on next matching time (it will not execute the moment you start).  `myJob.start()` is same as `true` in constructor - they both launch Cron, but do not execute the onTick.  If you want to execute onTick function the moment you start Cronjob, you have to call it directly, not through cron.

Comment: oh,i see.i was so stupid to think that '*/10' means every 10 seconds.thank you so much for explaining me so patiently.

Comment: @MarsOnly happy to help. Without you, I would not even know about node-cron ;-) . By the way, if you are totally happy with the answer, upvoting it as well is very valuable for authors of answers. Good luck.